# How to continue a landscape orientation for a particular div tag while converting html to pdf in itext 7?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

```
<div isLandscape=false style="page-break-after:always">
<p class="title">
this is the first title in the portrait mode
</p>
<div>
this is the content following the first title in portrait mode
</div>
</div>
<div isLandscape=true style="page-break-after:always">
<p class="title">
this is the first title in the Landscape mode
</p>
<div style="page-break-after:always">
this is the content following the first title in Landscape mode
</div>
<p>
This content which is on the next page should be rendered on a landscape 
page and all the content in this parent div should continue to be in the 
landscape page.
</p>
</div>
<div isLandscape=false style="page-break-after:always">
<p class="title">
this content should be rendered on the portrait page and continue to be on a 
portrait page till the end of the parent div tag.
</p>
</div>
```

I want the first div content to be on the portrait A4 page and the next to be on the landscape A4 page.This should be not by rotation but by actually setting the pagesize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can achieve this is by parsing to layout elements instead of straight to a file or `pdfDocument`, and apply the page size modification using page events.

I made a quick example below that switches orientation every X pages:

```
public void createPdfFromHtml(String htmlSource, String pdfDest, String resoureLoc) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    File pdf = new File(pdfDest);
    pdf.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    //convertToElements takes the string containing the HTML as input
    byte[] bytes = StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(new FileInputStream(htmlSource));
    String html = new String(bytes);


    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfDest);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc,pageSize);


    // Create the page size modifying event handler
    PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4;
    pageSize = pageSize.rotate();//Start in landscape
    int differentPageSizeInterval = 5;
    PageSizeModifier pageSizeModifier = new PageSizeModifier(doc, differentPageSizeInterval, pageSize);
    //Register it to the pdfDocument and set it to trigger at the start of a page
    pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE,pageSizeModifier);
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    converterProperties.setBaseUri(resoureLoc);
    //Convert the html to elements
    try {
        //parse and return the top level elements of the <body>
        List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(html, converterProperties);
        for (IElement ele : elements) {
            //Add the elements to the layout document
            doc.add((BlockElement) ele);
        }
        doc.close();
    } catch (PdfException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected class PageSizeModifier implements IEventHandler {

    Document doc;
    int interval;
    int counter;
    PageSize pageSize;

    public PageSizeModifier(Document doc, int interval,PageSize pageSize) {
        this.doc = doc; //A reference to the layout document must be kept so we can change the margins on the fly
        this.interval = interval;
        this.counter = 1;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;//Start out in landscape
    }
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        if(counter == interval){
            //Rotate
            pageSize = pageSize.rotate();
            //For the rendering framework, change the default page size
            doc.getPdfDocument().setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);

            //because the page was already created, we need to update the various boxes determining the pagesize
            //By default, only the trim and mediabox will be present
            ((PdfDocumentEvent) event).getPage().setMediaBox(pageSize);
            ((PdfDocumentEvent) event).getPage().setTrimBox(pageSize);

            //Reset the counter
            counter = 1;

        }else{
            counter++;
        }

    }
```